# ExtJS pagination is not working and Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, pagination, store

Pagination is not working and my console is showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined", I don't know where I am doing wrong.

I'm using eclipse for the development.

Below is my code please guide me I am new in ExtJS.

js_ext.js

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
     var itemsPerPage = 6;
    
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'mydata',
    fields:[ 'title', 'desc', 'year', 'lang', 'name', 'rate', 'special'],
    pageSize: itemsPerPage,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url: 'mystoredata.js',
        enablePaging: true, 
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    },
});
    
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

    title: 'Movie Grid',
    store: 'mydata',

    columns: [
        { text: 'Title', dataIndex: 'title', flex: .2 },
        { text: 'Description', dataIndex: 'desc', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Release Year', dataIndex: 'year' },
        { text: 'Language', dataIndex: 'lang' },
        { text: 'Director', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Rating', dataIndex: 'rate' },
        { text: 'Special Features', dataIndex: 'special', flex: .14}
    ],
    height: 330,
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: 'mygrid',
    
    selModel: {
          selType: 'checkboxmodel'
      },


    tbar: {
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            displayInfo: true,
            store: 'mydata',
            pageSize: itemsPerPage
    }
});

 store.load({params:{start:0, limit:6}});

});
```

When I'm trying to use `store.load` function it throws the error `store is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the created store instance to a variable and then assign this variable to both your grid and paging toolbar:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { ...
...
store: myStore, // both in grid an paging toolbar
...
```

With `autoLoad: true` as you use you don't need to call `load` on the store.
You don't have to worry about setting `start` and `limit`, ExtJS will automatically add these as `pageSize` is set.